# Simpler Way to Building an SQL Statement from a VB.net form?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a form that builds an SQL statement from user input. The controls include CheckBox, TextBox, ComboBox, and DateTimePicker.

They are grouped in a global array for each section of the form. Some statements will check against multiple controls for an SQL command.

Right now I use a bunch of if...else if...else statements to build my SQL statement, checking against check states, text changes and so on. However, this method has proven to be unstable if I change the control index in the array.

I'm looking for an easier way to build the SQL statement in one go. I've thought about changing a string for each control group every time a control's status has changed, thus taking away the need to build the SQL when the user wants to run it, however I'm not sure if that is a good way to handle it.

Is there an alternative method to the one I currently use? Will the one I've been thinking about switching to worth the effort?

Edit: As requested, here some of the code I currently use.

```vb
'icControls is the class that has all of the global arrays
'DefaultStrings is the module that has the default strings in the textboxes

Dim sqlWhere As String = "Where "
If Me._icControls.chkBasic(0).Checked = True And Me._icControls.chkBasic(1).Checked = True _
                And Me._icControls.chkBasic(2).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += """Field1"" in('A', 'B', 'C')"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(0).Checked = True And Me._icControls.chkBasic(1).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += """Field1"" in('A', 'B')"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(0).Checked = True And Me._icControls.chkBasic(2).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += """Field1"" in('A', 'C')"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(1).Checked = True And Me._icControls.chkBasic(2).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += """Field1"" in('B', 'C')"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(0).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += """Field1"" in('A')"
        sqlWhere += " AND (SUBSTR(""Tag #"", 1, 1) not in('#') and ""Inventory Type"" in('F'))"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(1).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += """Field1"" in('B')"
        sqlWhere += " AND (SUBSTR(""Tag #"", 1, 1) in('R', 'A', 'Z') and ""Inventory Type"" in('R'))"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(2).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += """Field1"" in('')"
        sqlWhere += " AND (SUBSTR(""Tag #"", 1, 1) in('W'))"
End If

If Me._icControls.chkBasic(4).Checked = True And Me._icControls.chkBasic(5).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += " AND ""Field2"" in('A', 'B')"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(4).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += " AND ""Field2"" in('A')"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(5).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += " AND ""Field2"" in('B')"
End If

If Me._icControls.chkBasic(6).Checked = True And Me._icControls.chkBasic(7).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += " AND ""Field3"" in('A', 'B')"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(6).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += " AND ""Field3"" in('A')"
ElseIf Me._icControls.chkBasic(7).Checked = True Then
        sqlWhere += " AND ""Field3"" in('B')"
End If

If Me._icControls.txtMaterial(0).Text.ToString() <> DefaultStrings.Material(0) Then
        sqlWhere += " AND ""Material"" in('" + Me._icControls.txtMaterial(0).Text.ToString() + "')"
End If
```

Comment: @Adam Added some code. Should be enough, it's pretty much what all the rest of it is doing.

Comment: What type of SQL statements (INSERT, SELECT WHERE, ...) do you build ?

Comment: @Graffito I build Select statements

Comment: Create a "Tuple<string,List<string>> selectValues"  to store the fieldname and list values.  Build a "List<string> field1Value" containing A,B and/Or C depending on the controls checked. Add <"Field1",field1Value) to selectValues. Same process for other fields. Then format your SQL Where clause from SelectValues.

Comment: Why you need to keep control in the array? Why you cannot use them by their names?

Comment: @Graffito Why can't I just use a string in place of the List<string> since I'm only adding one value?

Comment: @Fabio I can when it's in their respective form, but when I need it in other forms and files, I can't access them.

Comment: Then it seems like if `icControls.chkBasic(0)` and (1) and (2) checkboxes will be unchecked then your WHERE Staement will be invalid. It will start with `WHERE AND`

Comment: The list<string> will store all the values to be added within the IN, e.g if the list contains the 2 strings "A" and "B", the result in the where clause will be IN('A','B').

Comment: You don't need access a controls, you need only values of the controls. And on my opinion original approach with generating sql statement only when it is needed is better then update it every time when control changes value

Comment: @Fabio Yes, I'm aware of that. I have a check for it at the end before the SQL is ran to catch and remove the first AND if it follows the Where.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I proposed in comments will comprise the following steps:

- Create the List< Tuple < string,List >> selectValues that will contain one item per field, each item (a Tuple) composed of field name and field values.
- Create the Tuple < string,List> field1Values = new Tuple <"Field1,field1Values> and the inner List. Add field1Values to selectValues
- Loop on _icControls.chkBasic items and add item value to field1 values List,
- Same process for field2Values, field3Values,...
- Loop on SelectValues ignoring the fields with an empty list to build SQL command : get field name from element1 of the tuple and values from the list contained in element2.

Answer (score 0):

I think approach with generating SQL statement only when you need it(after pressing a button) is better then generating it every time when values changes.
Then you don't need checking value every time,
check it ones and save result to the variable

```vb
Dim chkControl0 As CheckBox
Dim chkControl1 As CheckBox
Dim chkControl2 As CheckBox
Dim chkControl3 As CheckBox
Dim chkControl4 As CheckBox
Dim chkControl5 As CheckBox
Dim chkControl6 As CheckBox
Dim chkControl7 As CheckBox

Private Function GenerateField1WhereClause() As String
    Const CHK0 As String = "'A'"
    Const CHK1 As String = "'B'"
    Const CHK2 As String = "'C'"
    Dim checked As New List(Of String)()
    If chkControl0.Checked = True Then checked.Add(CHK0)
    If chkControl1.Checked = True Then checked.Add(CHK1)
    If chkControl2.Checked = True Then checked.Add(CHK2)
    If checked.Count = 0 Then Return String.Empty
    If checked.Count = 1 Then
        Select Case checked(0)
            Case CHK0
                Return String.Format("""Field1"" = {0} AND (SUBSTR(""Tag #"", 1, 1) NOT IN('#') AND ""Inventory Type"" IN ('F'))", CHK0)
            Case CHK1
                Return String.Format("""Field1"" = {0} AND (SUBSTR(""Tag #"", 1, 1) in('R', 'A', 'Z') and ""Inventory Type"" in('R'))", CHK1)
            Case CHK2
                Return String.Format("""Field1"" = {0} AND (SUBSTR(""Tag #"", 1, 1) in('R', 'A', 'Z') and ""Inventory Type"" in('R'))", CHK2)
        End Select
        String.Format("Field1 = {0} AND (SUBSTR(""Tag #"", 1, 1) in('W'))")
    Else
         Return String.Format("""Field1""  IN ({0})", String.Join(",", checked))
    End If
End Function

Private Function GenerateField2WhereClause() As String
    Const CHK0 As String = "'A'"
    Const CHK1 As String = "'B'"
    Dim checked As New List(Of String)()
    If chkControl4.Checked = True Then checked.Add(CHK0)
    If chkControl5.Checked = True Then checked.Add(CHK1)
    If checked.Count = 0 Then Return String.Empty
    Return String.Format("""Field2"" IN ({0})", String.Join(",", checked))
End Function

Private Function GenerateField3WhereClause() As String
    Const CHK0 As String = "'A'"
    Const CHK1 As String = "'B'"
    Dim checked As New List(Of String)()
    If chkControl6.Checked = True Then checked.Add(CHK0)
    If chkControl7.Checked = True Then checked.Add(CHK1)
    If checked.Count = 0 Then Return String.Empty
    Return String.Format("""Field3"" IN ({0})", String.Join(",", checked))
End Function
```

Then using function and checking if result empty or not you can create your WHERE clause

```vb
Private Function GenerateWhereClause() as String
    Dim where As New StringBuilder()
    Dim field1 As String = Me.GenerateField1WhereClause()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(field1) = false Then
        where.Append(field1)
    End If
    Dim field2 As String = Me.GenerateField2WhereClause()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(field2) = false Then
        If where.length > 0 Then where.Append(" AND ")
        where.Append(field2)
    End If
    Dim field3 As String = Me.GenerateField3WhereClause()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(field3) = false Then
        If where.length > 0 Then where.Append(" AND ")
        where.Append(field3)
    End If
    If where.Length > 0 Then where.Insert(0, "WHERE ")
    Return where.ToString()
End Function
```

If you need values of the checkboxes outside of your form, just create a property which return only value

```vb
Public ReadOnly Property Check0 As Boolean
    Return Me.chkControl0.Checked
End property
```